# How to put an element in hover state when scrolled down using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a div element which when scrolled down will change properties drastically. [Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/somethingoverhere/pen/NWpqONL) example of how I want it to work.

Instead of hover I want it so that when scrolled down, the page wide div will turn into that little circle div which when clicked will function as a back to the top button. It doesn't matter if more classes are added or anything of that sort. I am very new to js and I tried a few things and also googled about it, I got the scroll code from w3school's how to make a back to top button guide which specifies that when scrolled down by 20px the code would react, but I don't know how to turn the JavaScript to JS when scrolled down along with the transformation of the div.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement scroll to top functionality, very common these days in most of the web app.

You need to keep below things and design that feature.

1. There is one header, that should have a reference ID with hash to scroll back to top
2. Create a button that will always static position (JS) button, will show up when user scroll the window
3. Bind click event on the button that scroll back to top

Here is the you can see [this](https://codepen.io/joshuamasen/pen/OYaYbL) implementation and use it.

.html

```
<h1 class="intro-copy">  
Scroll down to use this simple back-to-top button made with modern vanilla javascript.
</h1>

<a class="top-link hide" href="" id="js-top">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 6"><path d="M12 6H0l6-6z"/></svg>
  <span class="screen-reader-text">Back to top</span>
</a>
```

.css

```
body {
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

.intro-copy {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 50vh auto;
  max-width: 15em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-link {
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 3em 3em 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: .25em;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  
  &.show {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  &.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }

    svg {
        fill: #000;
        width: 24px;
        height: 12px;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: #E8E8E8;

        svg {
            fill: #000000;
        }
    }
}

// Text meant only for screen readers.
.screen-reader-text {
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);

    &:focus {
        display: block;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        z-index: 100000; // Above WP toolbar
        clip-path: none;
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 15px 23px 14px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: normal;
        color: #444;
        font-size: 1em;
        clip: auto !important;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
// Set a variable for our button element.
const scrollToTopButton = document.getElementById('js-top');

// Let's set up a function that shows our scroll-to-top button if we scroll beyond the height of the initial window.
const scrollFunc = () => {
  // Get the current scroll value
  let y = window.scrollY;
  
  // If the scroll value is greater than the window height, let's add a class to the scroll-to-top button to show it!
  if (y > 0) {
    scrollToTopButton.className = "top-link show";
  } else {
    scrollToTopButton.className = "top-link hide";
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunc);

const scrollToTop = () => {
  // Let's set a variable for the number of pixels we are from the top of the document.
  const c = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  
  // If that number is greater than 0, we'll scroll back to 0, or the top of the document.
  // We'll also animate that scroll with requestAnimationFrame:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame
  if (c > 0) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollToTop);
    // ScrollTo takes an x and a y coordinate.
    // Increase the '10' value to get a smoother/slower scroll!
    window.scrollTo(0, c - c / 10);
  }
};

// When the button is clicked, run our ScrolltoTop function above!
scrollToTopButton.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  scrollToTop();
}
```

Comment: firstly thank you for responding but I don't need that I guess I didn't explain very well but basically whenever the page gets scrolled down the div will go into the hover state like I showed in the codepen. So when the page is scrolled less than 20px it will be a big div represented by the unhovered state of the div and when scrolled it should be the hovered state like in the codepen I couldn't find a way to use JS to an element to it's hover state so asked this.